# How to break $.each iteration inside onload ("image") function

Tags: jquery

I have the following code :

```
$.each(images, function (intValue, currentElement) {    
    $("#image").on('load', function () {
        if (($("#image").width() < 50) || ($("#image").height() < 50)) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something
            return false; // not working !!!
        }    
    }).attr("src", currentElement).hide()
      .each(function () {
            if ($(this).complete) $(this).trigger('load');
      });    
});
```

i want to break out the *each iteration* inside else statement, so i add `return false`, but it doesn't works, i think because of `.on('load', function()....`

Comment: This sounds like an x/y problem.. What you're trying to do doesn't make any sense. The loop is going to attach the load function to each image, THEN those load functions will run. How could they stop the loop that already happened?

Comment: try `$(document).on('load', '#image', function () {`

Comment: @m59 i want to loop through an array "images" which contains absolute url of some images, then i try to load each image one by one, when i load the first i test if width < 50 ..., if yes i try to load the second image ... but if width >= 50 i want to break the loop, what is wrong in my code i don't understand what do you means

Comment: @medBo that's incorrect. The loop is done. You want to stop the loading. I'll show you how to do this, and if it is correct, I'll edit your answer to be appropriate.

Comment: If I had understood your question correctly, you are trying to check first image in list whether it's width is less than `50` if yes you want to load other items else you want to cancel loading other images. Am I correct?

Comment: @m59 ok if i understand load function is attached to the loop and loading is done for all images, so how to stop loading :D

Comment: @redV yes it's correct :)

Comment: @medBo Please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/aJUFuDa/8/edit)

```
var imageSources = [
  'http://placehold.it/10x10',
  'http://placehold.it/25x20',
  'http://placehold.it/50x50',
  'http://placehold.it/100x500'
];

var $myImage = $('#myImage');

var current = 0; //tracks which url is currently loaded
$myImage.load(function() {
  //use $(this) if you need jQuery here also
  if (this.width < 50 || this.height < 50) {
    ++current; //update tracker
    this.src = imageSources[current]; //load new item
  }
});

$myImage.attr('src', imageSources[0]);
```

#### Old answer:

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/oRAPeBO/2/edit)

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');

for (var i=0; i<imgs.length; ++i) {
  addLoadEvents(i);
}

function addLoadEvents(i) {
  imgs[i].addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    myImgFunction(this, i, e);
  });
}

var done = false;
function myImgFunction(elem, i, e) {
  //stop functions from running on items that are to be removed.
  if (done) { return false; }
  //do whatever you want here...use "removeTheRest" for whatever condition the remaining images need to be removed.
  if (i > 2) {
    done = true;
    removeTheRest(i);
  }
}

function removeTheRest(i) {
  //get rid of the rest of the images
  var imgLength = imgs.length;
  for (var j=i; j<imgLength; ++j) {
    console.log(j);
    imgs[j].parentNode.removeChild(imgs[j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: your code seem a little complicated can you modify it to use an array of image urls rather than html elements

Comment: @medBo It's not complicated at all. Your code is much more complicated because you have to consider everything at once. In my code, you only have to look at one things at a time. However, I now see better what you're trying to do. I'm loading new elements rather than changing the src on the same element.

Comment: by the line  this.src = imageSources[current]; //load new item you are not in the load event

Comment: @medBo Not in the load event? How is it being executed then? lol

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?. In your case why it is not working is image loading is asynchronous process, by the time of image load fires the loop will be completed with all the load events attached and they will fire. In each iteration `return false` will not work cause there is no image is loaded yet. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jr7t8/2/)

```
    var imageSources = [
      'http://placehold.it/10x10',
      'http://placehold.it/25x20',
      'http://placehold.it/50x50'
    ];
    var loadImg = function loadImages(images){
        $("#image").on('load', function () {
           if (($("#image").width() < 50) || ($("#image").height() < 50)) {
              debugger;
              images.shift();
              loadImages(images);
           } else {
               debugger;
               $('#image').attr('src', images[0]);
               return false;
           }    
        }).attr("src", images[0]).each(function () {
            if ($(this).complete) $(this).trigger('load');
        });
    }
    loadImg(imageSources);
```

Comment: don't know why firebug show me "too much recursion"

return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery ); ...

Comment: Please check it now @medBo. Now I removed recursion.

Comment: error is gone now but in result i can't see what i expect, before when i used $.each i get the expected image but now nothing :(

Comment: i think because the image expected to be shown is in the last of array, are your code take the last image too

Comment: @medBo Yes it will check one by one, at ay point of time if any image is failed then it will break the loop and stop checking next items in array. Assumption made as per comments. So if last image is passing the rule and not previous elements then it will fail.

Comment: it seem that the line loadImages(images); which replace recursion is executed just once !! try it and you will see

Comment: If the first image in images array list is failed then it will not check next images.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41843/discussion-between-medbo-and-redv)